# Using smartctl without sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, smart-device

I have an Ubuntu server (`3.19.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:31:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 Linux-3.19.0-21-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-15.04-vivid`). It has a 4-disk RAID-6 array. I keep an eye on the health of the disks by periodically interrogating each disk with this piece of Python-code:

```
t1 = time.time()
if ((t1 - self.lasttime) > (4.5*60)):
  self.vars     = commands.getoutput("sudo smartctl -A " + self.diskid + " |awk 'NR>4'").splitlines()
  self.health   = commands.getoutput("sudo smartctl -H " + self.diskid + " |awk 'NR>4'").splitlines()
  self.selftest = commands.getoutput("sudo smartctl -l selftest " + self.diskid + "  |grep '\# 1'")
  self.lasttime = t1
```

where `self.diskid` is (obviously the disk-ID) e.g. `/dev/sdc`.
I use the output of these commands to track various disk parameters (e.g. temperature and state) and post-process the data for (graphing and textual states) reporting on a webpage.

I also like to keep an eye on the logs, but the above command spams `journalctl` with lots of stuff like this:

```
Jun 17 16:46:07 boson sudo[18429]: beheer : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdc
Jun 17 16:46:07 boson sudo[18429]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 17 16:46:07 boson sudo[18429]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

One of these for each smartctl command issued and that repeats for each disk.
This makes it hard to spot oddities when browsing through the logs. I know about the filtering capabilities of `journalctl` they are no real help. It also causes the logs to become unreasonably large, which I think is an issue.

So, to relieve `journalctl` I thought I might forego with the `sudo`. But, obviously `smartctl` requires root-permissions.

I added `nobody ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/smartctl` to `/etc/sudoers`.

Then e.g. `smartctl -H /dev/sdc` seems to work but returns an error:

```
Smartctl open device: /dev/sdc failed: Permission denied
```

So, I added my administrator account to the `disk` group.

Now, `smartctl -H /dev/sdc` still seems to work but returns this message.

```
Probable ATA device behind a SAT layer
Try an additional '-d ata' or '-d sat' argument.
```

And that's where I'm kinda stuck.

For those wondering:

```
$ sudo smartctl -H /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.19.0-21-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

So, using `sudo` gives the expected results.

`smartmontools` is installed:

```
$ dpkg -l smartmontools
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                        Version            Architecture       Description
+++-===========================-==================-==================-===========================================================
ii  smartmontools               6.3+svn4002-2      amd64              control and monitor storage systems using S.M.A.R.T.


$ systemctl list-units |grep smart
  smartd.service        loaded active running   Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon
```

Comment: You might look into installing and configuring `smartmontools` as an alternative...

Comment: @twalberg :  `smartmontools` IS installed. That's how I got `smartctl` :-)

Comment: Ah, yes... `smartd` (which is also in that package) is what I was thinking of - it can be configured to do various types of notifications, schedule periodic testing, etc... Rather than having to roll your own...

Comment: I'm using that too. Please elaborate.

Comment: I just re-read the `smartd` manpage. The daemon offers none of the functionality I'm trying to achieve. I've added extra info in the OP about the desired functionality, although that is IMHO irrelevant to the question.

Comment: As an aside, calling Awk from Python is insane.

Comment: @tripleee :  Now you mention it. It is kinda stupid like that. I developed the original code as a bash script and later wrapped it into Python. Never optimised it though. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3):

1. Restrict users who can run this this command. Something like this: `sudo chmod o-x /usr/sbin/smartctl && sudo chown :admin /usr/sbin/smartctl`
2. Use `sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/smartctl` to allow any who run this command - it will run with root permissions.

I suppose this should be run in the install script cause command `smartctl` is useless without root permissions and should be run only by admin group

Comment: Adding new SUID programs is generally ill-advisable.

Comment: @tripleee generally yes. But do you see any issues in this specific case?

Comment: If this solves the `sdc` error message where `sudo` does not, please explain how it works.  If not, I don't see how this brings any benefit over what the OP is already doing.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I added my administrator account to the disk group.
>
> Now, `smartctl -H /dev/sdc` still seems to work but returns this
>   message.
>
> ```
> Probable ATA device behind a SAT layer
> Try an additional '-d ata' or '-d sat' argument.
> ```

Did you try the extra `-d ata` or `-d sat` as suggested?  Under my setup, adding the device type (`-d ata` for mine) gets it working, once the user is in the 'disk' group.

I fired up `strace` briefly, and it seems that one of the `ioctl()` calls that it does to determine what type of device is being used requires root permissions or something?